# Django: Order object depending in two values

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I have this:

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    first_thread_notification = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    second_thread_notification = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I need to order the objects depending on the sum of the 2 objects:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-first_thread_notification' + '-second_thread_notification']
```

I know this is incorrect but how can I do it?

**EDIT**

```
class ManagerSum(models.Manager):
    Thread.objects.annotate(
       total=ExpressionWrapper(
       F('first_thread_notification') + F('-second_thread_notification'), 
       output_field=IntegerField(),
       )
    ).order_by('-total')

class Thread(models.Model):
    first_thread_notification = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    second_thread_notification = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    total_notifications = ManagerSum()

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-total_notifications']
```

is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotate to [sum them via an F expression.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, ExpressionWrapper
Thread.objects.annotate(
    total=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('first_thread_notification') + F('-second_thread_notification'), 
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('-total')
```

Comment: So, do I need to add it in the meta class or in the model class?

Comment: Unfortunately no, read this part of the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset That should help you along to the right path.